# Accelerator Example Phonegap not functioning

Tags: html, mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

I included a page in my program that displays the accelerator data from the mobile device using PhoneGap Cordova. I'm also using JQuery. My problem is that it's not displaying the data. What am I doing wrong? I'm very new to mobile HTML and JavaScript development.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
    <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head> 
    <body> 

    <div data-role="page" id="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page One</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">   
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#page2">Page Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page3">Page Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page4">Page Four</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page6">Accelerator Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page5">Alert Example</a></li>
            </ul>       
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

     //code from other pages excluded

    <div data-role="page" id="page6">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Accelerator example 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.getElementById("ready").innerHTML = "false";
    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.getElementById("ready").innerHTML = "true";
        navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
    //
    function onSuccess(acceleration) {
        /*alert('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');
              document.writeln(
              'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');*/
             /* $("ax").html(acceleration.x);
    $("ay").html(acceleration.y);
    $("az").html(acceleration.z);
    */
    document.getElementById("ax").innerHTML = acceleration.x;
    document.getElementById("ay").innerHTML = acceleration.y;
    document.getElementById("az").innerHTML = acceleration.z;
    }

    // onError: Failed to get the acceleration
    //
    function onError() {
        alert('onError!');
    }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>getCurrentAcceleration</p>
    <p id="ax"></p>
    <p id="ay"></p>
    <p id="az"></p>
    <p id="ready"></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know that may sound rude, but: have this device an accelerometer?

Comment: Yes I am sure it has one, but thanks for asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example has two body tags and the content from the second body is not shown.

A working example of the accelerometer with jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap is available [here](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/source/browse/#svn/tags/r1.2/com.mds.apg/resources/jqm/phonegapExample).

If you're targeting Android the project creation wizard in [AppLaud Eclipse plugin](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/) or [AppLaud Cloud](http://applaudcloud.com/) will provision a fully running project for you.

Comment: I'm actually using Dreamweaver CS6 to port a working example to my phone. Two Body tags? I thought with Jquery Mobile I was supposed to put all my pages in the same html document. Also thanks for the example.